# How to configure WSS connection on Django Azure Web App

Tags: django, azure, websocket, azure-web-app-service

I've attempted to make an Azure Web App using Django. For the past couple days, I've mingled with Websockets for use for a real-time chat locally using the ws protocol. But, when deploying on Azure, I am forced to use the wss protocol due to the website being hosted on https. I've done some research on how to configure wss to no avail. Can anyone help?

I initiate the connection using:

```js
if (window.location.protocol == 'https:') {
  wsProtocol = 'wss://'
} else {wsProtocol = 'ws://'}
const chatSocket = new WebSocket(wsProtocol + window.location.host + "/");
```

This gives: "WebSocket connection to 'wss://pharma-send.azurewebsites.net/' failed:"

I'm using `django-channels`.

In the Startup Command of my Azure app I've tried running the Gunicorn server with ASGI using

`gunicorn pharmasend.asgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 -w 2 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker`

Although, this hasn't changed anything. Do I need to run an ASGI server, like Daphne or Uvicorn? Or, does Azure's Oryx do it for me?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> configure [WSS connection](https://www.stephenwenceslao.com/blog/create-daphne-asgi-ubuntu-2004) on Django Azure Web App

Install the `Channels` package in the Application.

Thanks [@divanov11](https://github.com/divanov11/django-channels-basic-chat) for the GitHub sample code which has the configuration to WebSocket.

> Do I need to run an ASGI server, like Daphne or Uvicorn?

Azure Oryx will not run the `ASGI server`.

Yes, we need to run any of the one ASGI server either `Daphne` or `Uvicorn`to configure `WSS` connections on Django Azure App

Thanks [@channels.readthedocs](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html#configuring-the-asgi-application) for the commands.

Install the [Daphne](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/asgi/) in the Application.

```cs
pip install Daphne
```